How to convert MeshGeometry3D to nifti (.nii.gz)?
I want to convert a C# .Net Framework 4.7.2 MeshGeometry3D to nifti. I am happy about simple libraries that I could use but I could not find anything useful, yet.

That's not a simple thing to do, since a mesh is a 3d surface represented by polygons, and Nifti stores 3d volumetric images.
